# PostgreSQL CASE usage in functions

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements, case, plpgsql

Can't we use `CASE` condition outside SQL `SELECT` statements?

E.g.:

```
CASE 
  WHEN old.applies_to = 'admin' THEN _applies_to = 'My Self'
  ELSE _applies_to = initcap(old.applies_to)
END
 _summary = _summary || '<li>Apply To: ' || _applies_to || '</li>';
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "_summary"
LINE 86: _summary = _summary || '<li>Apply To: ' || _applies ...
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This concerns the conditional control structure [**`CASE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) of the procedural language [**PL/pgSQL**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html), to be used in PL/pgSQL [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html), [procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html), or [`DO` statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html).
Not to be confused with the [`CASE` expression of SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE). Different language! Subtly different syntax rules.

While SQL `CASE` can be embedded in SQL expressions inside PL/pgSQL code, you cannot have stand-alone SQL `CASE` expressions (would be nonsense).

```sql
-- inside a plpgsql code block:
CASE 
   WHEN old.applies_to = 'admin' THEN
      _applies_to := 'My Self';
   ELSE
      _applies_to := initcap(old.applies_to);
END CASE;
```

You must use PL/pgSQL statements, terminated with a semicolon (`;`) and `END CASE;` to close it.

#### Is `ELSE` required?

**PL/pgSQL `CASE`** expects an `ELSE` branch and raises an error if it's missing when reached. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html##PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS-SIMPLE-CASE)

> If no match is found, the `ELSE` statements are executed;
> but if `ELSE` is not present, then a `CASE_NOT_FOUND` exception is raised.

You can use an empty `ELSE`:

```sql
CASE 
   WHEN old.applies_to = 'admin' THEN
      _applies_to := 'My Self';
   ELSE
      --  do nothing
END CASE;
```

This is different for **SQL `CASE`** where `ELSE` is optional. If the `ELSE` keyword is present an expression must be given. Without `ELSE`, it defaults to `NULL`. Like:

```
CASE WHEN old.applies_to = 'admin' THEN 'My Self'
  -- ELSE null  -- optional
END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick support Erwin. Very much appreciate it.

Comment: Another small question Erwin. Accroding to documentation ELSE condition of CASE statement is optional. But when I try to run series of WHEN conditions with statements without ELSE, Query browser giving me errors. `ERROR:  case not found. HINT:  CASE statement is missing ELSE part.` If you need I'll post relevant script part.

Comment: @Yohan: Please see additional answer.

Comment: @Brandstetter: Thank you very much again. I went through documentation & saw that CASE_NOT_FOUND story. However I just found that we can omit ELSE if data I am looping through doesn't come to ELSE of CASE. Which mean CASE should have WHEN conditions to satisfy all data patterns which I am conditionally check. If my comment is not clear I'll post the script part which I used.

Comment: @Yohan: It would be unwise to skip the ELSE clause. Always include it. Raise an exception with an informative msg. in the ELSE clause if it should not occur.

Comment: @Brandstetter: Thanks for the advice. I have change the logic as you suggest.

Comment: Is very confusing you place on the SQL CASE, a link to the PostgreSQL syntax definition which does not state anything about it being optional.

Comment: @addons_zz: It is essential to know that the procedural `CASE` of plpgsql is different from the SQL `CASE` construct. And I am clearly stating the *difference*. Seems you have been victim to the same confusion. Also, the manual for SQL `CASE` *clearly* states that `[ELSE result]` is optional. Square brackets (`[]`) denote optional syntax elements.

Comment: Sorry, I have no Idea those square brackets `[]` means optional.